# Meaning of webpage link containing www23

Tags: malware, phishing

I have come across a number of websites which include links such as **www32**.example.com and also **www2**.example.com.

Why is there a number in the **www** part of the link?

Are these sites not legitimate? Thanks

Comment: Just to explain why you might be getting down-votes on this question: This site is generally intended to serve the IT Security professional community. Therefore, questions are expected to require a certain level of expertise to answer. However, anyone with even a modicum of understanding for how the Internet works would instantly recognize that anything preceding a domain name just serves to identify unique resources on that domain. The name of the server is not relevant - what content it serves is.

Comment: Any web server currently at "www.MyDomain.com" could just as easily be called "MyWWWServer.MyDomain.com" or "HeresMyPorn.MyDomain.com" or even "ftp.MyDomain.com" - the use of "www" as the name for a company's primary web server is just a general convention that most organizations follow. This is fundamental, "Internet 101", knowledge which is of little value to a community of professionals who presumably would already understand it.

Comment: I personally disagree with the downvoting of this question. It may not be requesting advice on rocket surgery, but it's still a valid concern that I'm sure many people have had.

Answer (score 1):

Simply could be multiple web servers in the farm. Very normal.